# Overlapping Text on Button

Tags: android, button, text

[image: Look at those pretty blue alt-texts]

I'd like to create a button for a calculator with normal and secondary text on it.  The picture below outlines it pretty succinctly.  My main concern is getting the secondary text to scale well on different devices.  This makes me think that I want to use a secondary text view, or find some way to use HTML to render the button secondary text in the button.

The problem I'm running into is that I have no idea what the most scalable and robust way of doing this is.

Is it necessary to create a custom button?  Or is there some way to get the button's setText() with HTML.fromHTML() to place the secondary text at the top left corner?  So far adding more lines makes the button stretch, and adding specific padding for the button doesn't scale to other devices.  I assume a background 9 patch image using the secondary text won't work either, as larger buttons won't scale the secondary text.

Anyone have any pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: I would use a RelativeLayout with a button selector as its background. That way you can position and size the text however you like, and it will still appear to the user as a button.

Comment: Tried it out, and it works perfectly!  The textviews sitting in front of the buttons don't even seem to absorb the ontouch event. You should submit that as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: I will put it in as an answer with a some sample code later today.

Comment: Any reason to use framelayout over relative?